# not printing web pages

Tags: printing

HI I have  an HP printer/ scanner, but when I try and print a web page it does not print, and also afterwards when I try to print from Libre office nothing, I have to delete the printer then re install it before it works again in office?  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install the printer driver. If you have HP Printer then you can use these link.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01174360

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I found two workarounds:

1. Open the print queue and remove the item that's blocking. You may have to pause printing and resume printing after deleting.
2. If this does not work, then you can open a terminal and run the following commands one by one:

```
sudo su
rm /var/spool/cups/*
exit
```

**WARNING:** Please be extra careful with the commands. The secondd command deletes all files in the folder! If you mistype the command you may delete all from another folder (if it exits)!

This will delete the temporary printing files and your printer should resume working. It is not quicker than deleting the printer from the list and adding it again, but you do not have to reconfigure the printer or set the default settings if you customised them.